# Powershell script last logon from ad users last 30 days

Tags: powershell

Hi everyone can someone help me with the following script. the next things must be added:

- Last logon date of the user
- Export to excel .csv

Much appreciated

```
$dcs = Get-ADDomainController -Filter { Name -like "*" }

# create hashtable to keep track of latest timestamps per user
$userLastLogonTable = @{}

foreach($dc in $dcs){
  # fetch all users from each DC
  Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties LastLogonDate -Server $dc | ForEach-Object {
    # Only add new timestamps to table if we either haven't seen the username before, or if the timestamp is newer than the current
    if(-not $userLastLogonTable.Contains($_.SAMAccountName) -or $userLastLogonTable[$_.SAMAccountName].LastLogonDate -lt $_.LastLogonDate){
      $userLastLogonTable[$_.SAMAccountName] = [pscustomobject]@{
        LastLogonDate = $_.LastLogonDate
        LogonServer   = $dc.Name
      }
    }
  }
}

# Now that we have a complete table of all users and their last logon timestamp, 
# we can then easily identify usernames that have no recent logons
$staleUserNames = $userLastLogonTable.PSBase.Keys |Where-Object { $userLastLogonTable[$_].LastLogonDate -le (Get-Date).AddDays(-30) }
```

Comment: just FYI ... the csv format IS NOT "an excel format" ... it is a standard that has been around for quite some time ... and excel contains import/export code for that file type. [*grin*] the CSV file type is not one of the excel-specific types.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon I already had some contact with Mathias, but didnt hear from him before. I am still a beginning Network admin and this is totally new for me. So sorry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the samaccountname value to the custom object:

```
$userLastLogonTable[$_.SAMAccountName] = [pscustomobject]@{
  SAMAccountName = $_.SAMAccountName
  LastLogonDate = $_.LastLogonDate
  LogonServer   = $dc.Name
}
```

Then filter on the *values* of the hashtable rather than the keys:

```
$staleUserEntries = $userLastLogonTable.PSBase.Values |Where-Object { $_.LastLogonDate -le (Get-Date).AddDays(-30) }
```

At which point you can export to CSV with `Export-Csv`:

```
$staleUserEntries |Select SAMAccountName,LastLogonDate |Export-Csv path\to\output.csv -NoTypeInformation
```